# Jenkins slave process on ubuntu not showing any logging

Tags: java, bash, jenkins, ubuntu-14.04

I have an Ubuntu VM dedicated as a Jenkins slave.  I wrote a one-liner script to run the slave jar, and I run that script from /etc/rc.local.  When I run the script manually, I get a few lines of output showing that it's working.  I've tried to define the rc.local line and the script so that it stores stdout/stderr in a file, but the file is always zero length, with a modtime of when I start the process.

In the following, some fields are elided with "=stuff=".

The end of my "/etc/rc.local" looks like this:

```
su -c "/home/=user=/bin/jenkinsconnect" =user=
exit 0
```

The "jenkinsconnect" script looks like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
java -jar /home/=user=/opnfv_slave_root/slave.jar -jnlpUrl https://=host=/ci/computer/att-build/slave-agent.jnlp -secret =secret= 2>&1 > /home/=user=/jc.log
```

As I said, "/home/=user=/jc.log" is always zero length, and the modtime is when I started the process.

Comment: `2>&1 > file` first redirects stderr to stdout and then redirects (only) stdout. You need to `>file 2>&1` to first redirect stdout to file and then redirect stderr to where stdout points to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `2>&1 > file` syntax will not work. You should either:

1. use `&>` for directing both stderr and stdout to a file, or
2. surround the entire command with parentheses to capture the output:

   `(java -jar /home/=user=/opnfv_slave_root/slave.jar ... 2>&1) > /home/=user=/jc.log`

Comment: Checking my previous use of this syntax, I realize now that I've always done "=process= > file 2>&1", which I assume has worked.  Nevertheless, I like the idea of being able to move the "> file" after the redirection indicator, which the "(=process= 2>&1) > file" syntax does. I've changed the script to use that syntax, and it works.